# Extract HTML elements with XSLT

Tags: html, xslt

I would like to extract everything between the `<head>` tag elements in an html page. Including link tags and script tags.

Assume the source code below is a snippet which would be part of a full html document.

The source:

```
...
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
    type="text/css" media="handheld" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
    type="text/css" media="handheld" />

 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="second.js"></script>
</head>
...
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="link"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This works fine if there is only one tag I'm trying to get. Is there a way I can process everything and only everything between the "head" tags.

The output I expect would be:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
    type="text/css" media="handheld" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
    type="text/css" media="handheld" />

 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="second.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fuller example of your source document, and an example of your expected output?

Comment: In general, you can use XSL only on XML-compliant data, such as XHTML.  If your input is not XHTML you will probably get parse exceptions at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an XSL *identity transform*

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

along with a template that prevents output of everything you don't want.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="html/head"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The second template, being more specific, will match the root and then apply the stylesheet to the contents of the `<head>` tag. The identity transform will output the desired tags.

Comment: +1 for a much more elegant answer than relying on `<xsl:for-each>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 'xsl:for-each' statement

```
<xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="head/*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use `<xsl:for-each>` element to select every XML element of a specified node-set.

Just loop through all the elements inside `head` tag and then use xsl-current() function to get the value of each element in a way like this;
`<xsl:value-of select="current()"/>`